# Komodo IDE 6's slow autocomplete problems with Javascript

Tags: ide, autocomplete, komodo

I've been trying out Komodo IDE 6 for the last few days.
I've always liked Komodo but I'm starting to get annoyed by something:

**The autocomplete is way too slow/buggy.**

Certain variables just won't give any autocomplete tips. Sometimes you have to backspace the dot and try over and over again.

It also has a hard time giving autocomplete info for an object that has been created using a class in a namespace.

Has anyone else had any problems with these things?
Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: You may have a better chance of getting a response at the official Komodo forum: http://community.activestate.com/forums/komodo-support

Comment: Same thing happens to me with eclipse. So annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JSDoc](http://community.activestate.com/forum-topic/getting-more-your-php-and-javascript-code) to add custom autocomplete calltips.

Comment: Adding JSDoc comments really helped. I even made a dummy file containing object layouts I could reference later on, and Komodo would autocomplete them perfectly. A shame it doesn't do the same for node.js

Comment: Cool. You can add it to the [Komodo Edit wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Komodo_Edit) for future reference.